# Using Winston logger in Angular application

Tags: angular, logging, winston

I want to use winston logger on the client side logging as I plan to use the transport functionality to log all client information.

```
app.module.ts
  ..
  import { logger}  from 'winston';
  @NgModule({
        ...
        providers: [logger]
        ...
  }) 
  export class AppModule{}
```

But single my angular app is generated from angular cli, and uses webpack for dependency management,

it gives the following warning as soon as it complies.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/winston/node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js
127:29-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And the app does not load.

Same anyone come across the same issue and knows how to resolve it?.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `winston` in meant only for server side usage. See this issue for more information:

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/287

Comment: its supposed to be a universal logger. the above post is very old 2013.

Comment: yeah looks like that. true

Comment: here is another issue, that states it should work with browserify, but its bundle has 1MB, not very suitable solution for browser at all... https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/257

Comment: I found a SO link where it kind of seems promising, i will try it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840566/how-do-i-get-winston-to-work-with-webpack